# Reverse for 'product' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

I am Django newbie and learner, just follow the tutorial and got stuck. When I add a SlugField in django models.py and make a get_absolute_url but the reverse error is coming in 
navbar. Reverse for 'product' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['product/(?P[^/]+)/$'].

In my navbar the error is coming

navbar.html

```
<li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link waves-effect" href="{% url 'core:product' %}" target="_blank">Shop</a>
                </li>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.conf import settings

# Create your models here.

# Choices 
CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('S','Shirt'),
    ('P','Pants'),
    ('J','Jacket'),
    ('W','Watches'),
    ('E','Electronics'),
    ('SO', 'Shoes'),
)

LABEL_CHOICES = (
    ('P', 'primary'),
    ('S', 'secondary'),
    ('D', 'danger'),

)


class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES,max_length=3)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    slug = models.SlugField()
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('core:product', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
    orderd = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
    ItemListView,
    checkout,
    ItemDetailView,
)


app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',ItemListView.as_view(),name='item'),
    path('checkout/',checkout,name='checkout'),
    path('product/<slug>/', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name='product')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Item

# Create your views here.
class ItemListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name= 'home.html'

def checkout(request):
    return render(request,'checkou.html')


class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'product.html'
```

Comment: You must add slug to this url `{% url 'core:product' %}`.

Comment: Try `{% url 'core:product' slug=item.slug %}`